# Why fopen() returns null if I use run in Clion but returns a pointer in terminal?

Tags: c, shell, pointers, terminal, clion

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp= fopen("test","r");  //test.txt exists in the project; content: 11111;
    if (fp){
        int num;
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&num);
        printf("%d",num);
        fclose(fp);
    } else{
        printf("Null");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
//With "run" in IDE:
Null

//Using terminal in IDE:
(base) apple@xiaomibijiben-Air-3 untitled1 % clang main.c -o main   
(base) apple@xiaomibijiben-Air-3 untitled1 % ./main
11111%
```

My guess: run and run in terminal choose different file directories to read.

Comment: Without specifying a full path, the *current working directory* will be used, which is system (and context) specific.

Comment: Whenever you want to know why `fopen` fails, you should check `errno`.  (eg, `fprintf(stderr, "...: %s", strerror(errno))` or `perror(...);`

Comment: Anyway you are opening `"test"` but refer to `"test.txt"` in comment.

Comment: When you run from terminal, you control the starting directory. In the IDE, it may start in a different directory. Try opening the file with a full path. Or configure the IDE to start the program in the correct directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Clion not recognizing the current working path.

The workaround is as follows.

1. Open "Edit configurations"

[image]

2. Set "Working directory" as the absolute path for the current project.

[image]